# Javascript client side ssh / ping / scp

Tags: javascript, node.js, django, client-side, scp

I'm trying to build a web app that has the capability to scp, ssh, and ping devices on the local network from Javascript client-side. I'm very familiar with Django, but that's all server side code and won't be able to communicate with a device on the local area network.

Is there any way to do this in Javascript? I know that packages like [scp2](https://github.com/spmjs/node-scp2) in NodeJS do exactly what I want, but NodeJS is a server-side framework too. I'm looking for something that does what scp2 does, but client-side.

Comment: did you just ask about sshing in JS!??!

Comment: Yes I did just ask about sshing in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no browser-independent way to do this. You would have to write browser-specific extensions to be able to get access to TCP sockets and the like. Even then if you browserify `ssh2` or any of its dependents, you may run into other issues, such as missing node.js functionality not supported by browserify or the browser's extension API.

Alternatively, you could use something like Electron, but that's only if you don't mind the client being a separate application (but still web/JavaScript-based). That would also have the added benefit of having the `ssh2` or related code being completely compatible (since Electron uses node.js).